# Store Entity Framework Core SQLite file in project-relative subdirectory

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 app using Entity Framework Core and the SQLite Provider. I am trying to store the SQLite database file in a subdirectory (specifically `data\database\sqlite.db`) however if I set the Connection String to `Data Source=data\database\sqlite.db` I get the following exception as soon as I run `dbContext.Database.Migrate()`:

`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.`

If I set it to `Data Source=sqlite.db` it works as expected without throwing exceptions (but not in the directory I need it to be stored in). What do I need to do to store the SQLite database file in a sub-directory relative to the current working directory?

For the sake of context: I need the SQLite database file stored in a sub-directory because this app is running in a Docker Container, this specific directory is mapped to a Docker volume so the database persists when the container is replaced.

Comment: You may have to create the sub-directories before opening the connection.

Comment: Argh, that's it. Feel free to reply to post this as the answer and I'll mark it as answered. For the record, this was easily solved with a simple `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.
I suppose that you are running your app in a .NET Core environment. You can do this in your "DbContext" class:

```
internal class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        string baseDir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        //if "bin" is present, remove all the path starting from "bin" word
        if (baseDir.Contains("bin"))
        {
            int index = baseDir.IndexOf("bin");
            baseDir = baseDir.Substring(0, index);
        }

        //String interpolation to reach the right path
        options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={baseDir}YourFolderName\\SQLite.db");
    }

    public DbSet<YourEntity> Pluto { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify to `"Data Source=./data/database/sqlite.db"`

`"DefaultConnection": "DataSource=./data/database/sqlite.db"`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as other suggested, you need to install the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/) package.

Then open package manager console in visual studio as follows.

[image: Package Manager console in Visual Studio 2022]

If you use Developer Power shell, it will not work.